# Auto zoom when responsive on CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

when I make responsive with media queries on CSS, I get auto zoomed in when opening the website on mobile, so how can I adjust the zoom or what are affecting my page?

I tried this meta data here

```
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;700&family=Tajawal:wght@200;300;500;700&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

and still get the same result

Comment: Take a look at the [Viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case was because my CSS property. I have worked with the font size as 62.5% to make 1rem=10px and then when I tried to test the web on the phone or small media's I got an auto zoomed page when first login to it, I have changed the meta tag from 
to this one   and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the viewport meta tag and set the `initial-scale`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

> `initial-scale`
>
> Controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded.
> Minimum: 0.1. Maximum: 10. Default: 1. Negative values: ignored.

[MSDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)